# C program to find the Majority Element of Array using a user defined array size returns unexpected results

Tags: c, arrays, user-defined

I am trying to write a c program that prompts the user to input the size of an array (N) between 1 and 100. Then prompt the user to input array elements to the size of N.  Following that I want to display the aforementioned elements to the user, however, in run-time random, or what seems to be random numbers are displayed.  I am not sure if this is due to using malloc for user defined array size or what.  If you have any insight to what the problem may be I would really appreciate it.

Program:

```
int main()
{
    int N;
    int dW;
    int *inputArray;
    int counter;

do {
    // Prompts user to input array size up to 100
    printf("\nEnter the value of N up to 100:   \n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    // Uses pointer "inputArray" to pacify compiler and allocates size of N in memory for array
    inputArray = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    // Checks if temp is greater than 1 and less than 100, if yes prompts user to reenter N
    if (N >= 1 & N <= 100)
    {
        
        // Prompts user to input array numbers to the size of N
        for (counter = 0; counter < N; counter++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter the element %d: \n", counter);
            scanf("%d", &inputArray[counter]);
        }

        // displays numbers provided by user
        for (counter = 0; counter < N; counter++);
        {
            printf("%d\n", inputArray[counter]);
        }
        dW = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nIllegal Entry, enter a value between 1 and 100\n");
        dW = 1;
    }
    

} while (dW >= 1);
return 0;

}
```

Output:

> Enter the value of N up to 100:
> 5
>
> Enter the element 0:
> 1
>
> Enter the element 1:
> 2
>
> Enter the element 2:
> 3
>
> Enter the element 3:
> 4
>
> Enter the element 4:
> 5
>
> 00200000

Comment: `if (N >= 1 & N <= 100)`  =>  `if (N >= 1 && N <= 100)`

Comment: Also, do the check before you `malloc`. With your program as written, I can still type `2147483647` for `N` and cause your program to suddenly grab 8 whole GiB of RAM, even if you do bail right after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You should move `inputArray = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));` into the if-block so that you allocate memory only when you enter the block (and `N` is guaranteed to be between 1 and 100). Also there's no need to cast `malloc()` as `(int *)`.
2. Your second for-loop has a semi-colon at the end: `for (counter = 0; counter < N; counter++);`. If you leave it there, the for-loop will increment `counter` until `counter == N`, and then `printf("%d\n", inputArray[counter]);` will be called afterwards, but only once and with the wrong index (since `counter == N`, which would take you out of bounds).
3. You forget to `free(inputArray)` after you're done using it. You could do that right after `dW = 0;`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is on this line:

```
for (counter = 0; counter < N; counter++);
```

See that semicolon there? That essentially causes this line to do the same thing as:

```
for (counter = 0; counter < N; counter++) { /* do nothing */ }
```

Your `printf` block then runs, but only once, and the counter is equal to `N`, so you read whatever random data happens to be in memory directly past the end of `inputArray` in the heap.

Solution: Get rid of that semicolon.

Comment: That was it! Thank you for your response!